Scrollbar of Slider made by Swiper.js doesn't work
I've created a slider using Swiper.js, but the scrollbar isn't functioning properly. Specifically, when the second-to-last slide (the eighth one) comes to the center, the scrollbar's drag element is already at the right end. Normally, the drag should reach the right end when the ninth slide is centered. Could someone please provide a solution to fix this issue?


var swiper = new Swiper('.mySwiper', {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  loop: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    hide: true,
  },
});
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>



When the slidesPerView property is set to more than 1 and the loop property is set to true, the aforementioned bug occurs.
